# What do you call staff at polling stations?

Tags: phrase-request

What do you call staff at polling stations? I mean people who are employed during elections to count ballots, sign election protocols (or whatever you call those pieces of paper with final tallies).

Comment: Counting isn't done at polling stations, at least in the UK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the UK there are different roles:

The *Returning officer* is responsible for running the election in a constintuency. They are the most senior local official in a constituency. They also announce (or "return") the result.

*Presiding Officers* work at each polling station.  They run the polling station and are helped by *Poll Clerks*, who check each voter's details and hand out ballots.

Then at night, the ballots are returned to be counted, watched by the returning officer and counted by *Count Assistants*  (note, the count isn't done in the polling station)

In general all these are "Election staff", but I'd understand "Polling staff", "Poll workers" and so forth.

Answer (score 2):

"Poll workers" is the usual term in California.